# Setup cornjob via ftp

Tags: linux, cron, centos

I have the following problem:
I need to setup some cronjobs on a server but I don't have ssh access to it, I only have access to the server via web-ftp, so I can transfer files.
The server runs on CentOS release 6.10 (Final).
I know that the user cron files are in /var/spool/cron but I don,t have access there.
I also tried using to use .bash_profile, hoping it will trigger when i login in the web-ftp, but id doesn't.
Is there any other way I can set up those cronjobs?

Comment: this looks like non-legitimate access. You need to have proper access to the server.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author asks for non-legitimate access to linux server.

Comment: @DervişKayımbaşıoğlu It looks like it but I miss contextual information to be sure he is not just working for a sh***ty company with a sh**ty sys adm. Or maybe I am just naive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are basically asking us how to hack this server, for no ftp services properly configured would allow right access to anywhere outsite of `/home` (modulo chroot).

That being said, `/var/spool/cron` can contain user's cron jobs on centOS but the fact that you can't edit it from a loose ftp session is actually a good news.

Two options:

- ask the administrator to do it for you
- ask him to **symlic** the relevant `/var/spool/cron` file to a file you could edit in your user's home (if the ability to edit cronjob autonomously is a must)